# How to decode HTML entities in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a large collection of text files into a DataFrame. Initially it will just have one column, `value`. The text files use HTML encoding (i.e., they have `&lt;` instead of `<`, etc.). I want to decode all of them back to normal characters.

Obviously, I could do it with a UDF, but it would be super slow.

I could try regexp_replace, but it would be even slower, since there's over 200 named entities, and each would require its own regexp function. Each regexp_replace call will need to parse the entire line of text, searching for one specific encoded character at a time.

What is a good approach?

Comment: I would take the `regexp_replace` approach

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto it won't work, I'm afraid. I updated the question to talk about this. There's [200+ named entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). So many regexp_replace will be so slow that it's probably faster to just a UDF with a dictionary that stores the conversion map.

Comment: Language tag would be useful here.. In general UDFs are not the first choice but overall these are not "super" slow(er) although have other associated costs depending on a language and Spark version.

Comment: @zero323 ahh I didn't realize that. I thought all UDFs are slow. So I guess if I was writing in Scala, UDFs would be almost as fast as built-in functions (apart from not being part of optimization)? Unfortunately, I"m using python.

Comment: Python UDFs use completely different evaluation strategy.  So the cost is not the cost of UDF as such but passing data between JVM and Python interpreter.

Comment: @zero323 got it. so the answer is: "use UDF, but try to switch to Scala or Java", right? if you want maybe you can post it as an answer?

Comment: If I was sure how to answer I would, but I am not. Impact of moving data is significant but shouldn't be prohibiting and personally I find Python significantly when it comes to string and xml processing. Which version of Python do you use? Is the input just a plain text?

Comment: @zero323 Python 3.5. Plain text. Did you mean you find python significantly more convenient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you read plain text input I would simply skip UDF part and pass data to JVM after initial processing. With Python 3.4+:

```
import html
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType

def clean(s):
    return html.unescape(s), 

(sc.textFile("README.md")
    .map(clean)
    .toDF(StructType([StructField("value", StringType(), False)])))
```

Comment: So it still requires moving data from python to JVM, but at least not both directions as in the case of UDF right?

Comment: Yes it involves SerDe activity when data is passed to DataFrame. From the other hand it doesn't require additional dependencies so it can a win after all :) And truth be told if you don't plan to use anything beyond strict DataFrame then PySpark doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a built-in function for Spark 3.5.0+

[pyspark.sql.functions.url_decode.html](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.url_decode.html?highlight=decode)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35749196)

Comment: I figured mentioning that it's a built in function was the response, and I provided the link for reference.