# Efficiently clean HTML entities from a complex JSON file in PySpark

Tags: json, pyspark, html-entities, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am analysing some JSON data in Palantir Foundry using PySpark. The source is a 30MB uploaded JSON file containing four elements, one of which holds a table of some 60 columns and 20,000 rows. Some of the columns in this table are strings that contain HTML entities representing UTF characters (other columns are numeric or boolean). I want to clean these strings to replace the HTML entities with the corresponding characters.

I realise that I can apply `html.unescape(my_str)` in a UDF to the string columns once all the JSON data has been converted into dataframes.  However, this sounds inefficient.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38181647/937094) suggests it would be better to process the whole JSON file in one go, before converting it to a dataframe.  However, my current code uses `spark_session.read.json()` to go automatically from the raw file to a dataframe with a proper schema. I can't see how to modify it to include the `unescape()` stage without ending up with everything as `StringType()`, and I don't want to have to manually code the schema for every column of the nested data structure. My current code to read the JSON into a dataframe looks like this:

```py
from transforms.verbs.dataframes import sanitize_schema_for_parquet
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output, Check

@transform(
    parsed_output=Output("out_path"),
    raw_file_input=Input("in_path")
)
def read_json(ctx, parsed_output, raw_file_input):
    filesystem = raw_file_input.filesystem()
    hadoop_path = filesystem.hadoop_path
    paths = [f"{hadoop_path}/{f.path}" for f in filesystem.ls()]

    df = ctx.spark_session.read.json(paths)

    parsed_output.write_dataframe(sanitize_schema_for_parquet(df))
```

**How can I adapt this to `unescape()` the plain text of the JSON before it is parsed?**  Or would it actually be likely to be more efficient to `unescape` row by row and column by column later, using the parallelism in Spark, than trying to process the data as a single 30MB-long string?

An example of my JSON input format. The real input is about 30MB long and not pretty-printed.  The `Data` structure has many more rows, and around 60 columns. String columns are mixed in between numeric and boolean columns, in no particular order:

```json
{
    "Data": [
        {"Id": 1, "Lots": "more", "data": "of", "different": "types", "Flag1": true, "RefNumber": 17},
        {"Id": 2, "Lots": "of the string", "data": "includes entities like &#8804; in", "different": "places", "Flag1": false, "RefNumber": 17781}
    ],
    "TotalRows":2,
    "Warnings":null,
    "Errors":null
}
```

The final expected output from the above would end up as the below (I don't have any problem with processing the JSON into the right columns, it's just efficiently converting the HTML entities to characters that is an issue).  Note the math symbol `≤` in the 'data' field in row 2, rather than the entity `&#8804;`:

```
Id | Lots            | data                          | different | Flag1 | RefNumber
---+-----------------+-------------------------------+-----------+-------+-----------
 1 | "more"          | "of"                          | "types"   | true  |        17
 2 | "of the string" | "includes entities like ≤ in" | "places"  | false |     17781
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the answer that you linked ([How to decode HTML entities in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164532/how-to-decode-html-entities-in-spark/38181647#38181647)) is the right approach here. In order to achieve what you want (the convenience of letting Spark automagically infer a schema for you), here's how I would implement this in Foundry.

1. As a first step, do something like this (note: I didn't actually run this code, so there might be a trivial mistake or two, but hopefully it illustrates the idea)

```
@transform(
    output_json=Output("/NAMESPACE/PROJECT/datasets/preprocess/escaped_json"),
    input_json=Input("/NAMESPACE/PROJECT/datasets/preprocess/raw_json"),
)
def compute_function(output_json, input_json):
    input_fs = input_json.filesystem()
    output_fs = output_json.filesystem()

    def process_file(file_status):
        with input_fs.open(file_status.path) as input_fp:
            json_data = json.load(input_fp)
            clean_up_json_in_place(json_data)
            with output_fs.open(file_status.path, "w") as output_fp:
                json.dump(json_data, output_fp)

    input_fs.files().foreach(process_file)
```

2. As a second step, do exactly what you're currently doing now, but make the input `/NAMESPACE/PROJECT/datasets/preprocess/escaped_json`

Comment: Also worth noting that you may be able to do this with a single transform, because spark.read.json can take an RDD of strings, where each string is a JSON object. So your transform could look like dataset of files -> RDD of files -> RDD of strings -> map using a function that takes a JSON string, parses it, munges it, and converts the result back into a JSON string -> spark.read.json. I think that my example above is simpler, but it's a matter of taste!

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked for me. However, rather than use `json.read()` and `json.dump()`, I used a plain `read()` and `write()` to grab the JSON as a plain string, unescape() it and write back. If you want to process all the entities rather than a specific selection, then it's not necessary to parse the JSON structure first.

Comment: Cool! In principal, there could be weird edge cases where trying to unescape arbitrary JSON stringified data, instead of the string-typed data inside the parsed 
data, produces incorrect results (or at least, as a general principal of working with structured data like this, it's good to operate under the assumption that such edge cases may exist, even if it's not true specifically for the narrow case of JSON and HTML entity unescaping). What you did was probably fine, though - and likely more performant!

Comment: @AaronRubin - Thank you! Because of your answer and comment, I managed to find an answer using RDDs!

Answer (score 1):

An approach using RDDs:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
import html
import json


@transform(
    out=Output("out_path"),
    inp=Input("in_path"),
)
def compute(ctx, inp, out):
    spark = ctx.spark_session
    inp_fs = inp.filesystem()

    rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(inp_fs.hadoop_path).values()
    rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: json.loads(html.unescape(x))['Data'])
    rdd = rdd.map(json.dumps)
    df = spark.read.json(rdd)

    out.write_dataframe(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a `withColumn(cnameNew, udf_unescape(columnWithHtml))`. This should help you out.
Your udf could parse the html to dictionary and create a structT from it and return it. This should give you a complexTyped column and aid in further processing.
If you could share a sample of the data then I could extend on this answer.

Comment: If I can't unescape the raw JSON, this was the sort of approach I was going to use. However I've read that UDFs are slow, and I would have to iterate over dozens of columns.  I don't need to do any HTML processing: the data includes HTML entities like `&#8804;` (which I want to be replaced by a less-than-or-equals sign), but there are no actual HTML tags; the structure is all in JSON.